# Run same java program twice having static variable in class

Tags: java, variables, static, scope, class-variables

(I do not know whether i should ask this here or not)
I want to run the **same java program twice** which has most of the variables **static.**

if i ran this twice(concurrently) will these static variables have same values or different?

As the static variables are class variables, this is confusing me.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by running the same java program twice? Exiting it and re-running it? Rerunning a function? etc

Comment: I want to run it twice cuncurrently ,like java MyProgram and again java MyProgram,and both these instances will be executing at the same time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The static values are per-class and if you run the same java program twice, then it will create two JVMs (you'll see two java processes in the task list), which will load the class twice (once per JVM), so the static variables will not be shared.

Answer (score 1):

Each run will have its own JVM instance so static variables will not collide.

Answer (score 0):

If you are starting the application two times, for example, via:

```
java Your.MainClass
```

Then the values for the 2nd run will not be influenced by the first run. It's an entirely new process.

If, however you are running a static method two times, in the lifecycle of a single application, then, what I wrote above doesn't hold anymore.